# What's wrong with my useEffect code, and why is my state variable empty?

Tags: fetch, state, use-effect

I have a problem and I'm not sure what's causing the problem.

So I have done a fetch with an external api and I want to print out some of the information from the api. I have logged the data and the state variable to see if they return the data. My problem is that I don't get any data from the state variable in the console. When I log it in the console it only shows an empty array. But I get the data in the console when I'm logging console.log(data).

When I remove the empty array at the end of useEffect, it works in the console but it's an endless loop. Same thing happens if I put the state variable in the empty array.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

```
export const Communication = () => {
  const [article, setArticle] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.fortnox.se/3/articles', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Token': accessToken,
        'Client-Secret': clientSecret
      }
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setArticle(data)

        console.log('json', data)
        console.log('article', article)
      })
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about how JavaScript works. With this statement, you declare two variables:

```
const [article, setArticle] = useState([])
```

If you think about `article`, no call to an external function will be able to assign `article` to a new value. This is not just because it's `const`; even if `let` was used, an external function would not be able to change it; we don't have anything like pointers. It's no different than what's going on here:

```
function a() {
  let foo = 1;
  changeFoo(2);
}

function changeFoo(newValue) {
  // How do I change `foo` inside of function `a`? Spoiler, I cannot!
}
```

Similarly, calling `setArticle` *has no way to update the article value*. That's not how React works. Rather, the next time your component calls `useState`, it will receive the new value. Hence this is why:

```
setArticle(data);
console.log(article);
```

...is going to log the old value of `article`. This doesn't mean that `setArticle` didn't work; it means you're expecting React to be a little too magical. `article` will be assigned the new value on the next call to `useState` on the next render instead. If you want to log the changing article state, you'll want to do something more like:

```
export const Communication = () => {
  const [article, setArticle] = useState([])
  console.log('article', article);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.fortnox.se/3/articles', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Token': accessToken,
        'Client-Secret': clientSecret
      }
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(setArticle)
  }, [])

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I understand and it works