# Fetching data from api in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

Blog.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import Axios from "axios"

const Home = () => {
  const [blog, setBlog] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    loadBlog()
  }, [])

  const loadBlog = async () => {
    await Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/blog/get`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.data)
        setBlog(res.data.data)
        console.log(blog)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="col-lg-10">
          <h2> React CRUD Operation </h2>
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-2">
          <button> Add Blog </button>
        </div>
        <table className="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Picture</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Short Description</th>
              <th>Author</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>{blog.id}</td>
              <td>
                <img src={"../../../public/logo512.png"} alt="not available" />
              </td>
              <td>{blog.title}</td>
              <td>{blog.short_desc}</td>
              <td>{blog.author}</td>
              <td>
                <button>Edit</button> <button>Delete</button>{" "}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

I am fetching data from API and getting data. data is coming fine but it is not going in setBlog Hook. When I console response it is fine and data is fetched successfully but problem is with it is not going in setBlog hook.I am new to react and don't know why it is not going in setBlog Hook. any help will be appreicated

Comment: is `blog` an object or an array of objects?

Comment: Are you basing this on the fact that `console.log(blog)` isn't reflecting the blog you put in via `setBlog`?

Comment: I tried to explain how `setState` works in this answer; hopefully you find it useful. You're not the only one to get confused: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62460109/119549

Comment: it isarray of objects

Comment: Yes it's even not working when i want to use blog.something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the asynchronous nature of setting state. The code you have written,

```
.then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.data)
        setBlog(res.data.data)
        console.log(blog)
      })
```

here it executes synchronously, and the actual state update happens only after this is completed. if you console log the state variable within your function body, it will be updated by next render. e.g.

```
const Home = () => {
  const [blog, setBlog] = useState([])
  console.log(blog)
  .
  .
  .
```

First time when your component loads, `blog` value will be set to empty array (since that is passed as argument to `setState`). Then your data fetch will be called and the value for blog will be set. Now the `blog` value will be the array that you fetched. You can use this in the rendering.

You will need to map over the items in the blog to access it. Something like the following.

```
.
.
.
<tbody>
  {blog.map(function (entry) {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{entry.id}</td>
        <td>
          <img src={"../../../public/logo512.png"} alt="not available" />
        </td>
        <td>{entry.title}</td>
        <td>{entry.short_desc}</td>
        <td>{entry.author}</td>
        <td>
          <button>Edit</button> <button>Delete</button>{" "}
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  })}
</tbody>
.
.
.
```

Comment: Then what could be the solution